# Handling Messages from PubNub History as a "Global Variable"

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I'm trying to figure out the smartest, most reliable way to make my retrieved PubNub history accessible for several view controllers. As i see there are multiple ways to do that, but after a bunch of questions and articles i've read i can't decide which solution would be the best. Actually i think dependency injection would be the right idea in my case, but i'm not sure because i saw different solutions in the sample PubNub apps and overall i never heard about that so i would avoid it, if it's possible.

The possible ways:

**1. Using AppDelegate**

It could be the easiest way, but a lot of developers said, that AppDelegate is really not the best place for storing global data. So i wouldn't like to do this way.

**2. Using Singleton**

As an instance,i saw this solution in the PubNub's iPad demo app (*PNDataManager* file). I was sure this is the best way, but after i read [Stephen Poletto's article on objc.io about singletons](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/singletons.html) i've changed my mind, because he pointed to some issues, that can be substantial in my case.

It's a really useful article, that's worth reading, but actually i will grab only the thoughts that i found important in my situation.

> "suppose we’re building an app where users can see a list of their
>   friends. Each of their friends has a profile picture, and we want the
>   app to be able to download and cache those images on the device. With the dispatch_once snippet handy, we might find ourselves writing an SPThumbnailCache singleton"

Suppose we want to cache the `message` array instead of images, that we retrieved with this method `[PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel: withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error)}];` in our root view controller called `ViewController1`.

> "We continue building out the app, and all seems well in the world,
>   until one day, when we decide it’s time to implement the ‘log out’
>   functionality, so users can switch accounts inside the app. Suddenly,
>   we have a nasty problem on our hands: user-specific state is stored in
>   a global singleton. When the user signs out of the app, we want to be
>   able to clean up all persistent states on disk. Otherwise, we’ll leave
>   behind orphaned data on the user’s device, wasting precious disk
>   space. In case the user signs out and then signs into a new account,
>   we also want to be able to have a new SPThumbnailCache for the new
>   user. The problem here is that singletons, by definition, are assumed to be “create once, live forever” instances. You could imagine a few solutions to the problem outlined above. Perhaps we could tear down the singleton instance when the user signs out
>
> The problem here is that singletons, by definition, are assumed to be
>   “create once, live forever” instances. You could imagine a few
>   solutions to the problem outlined above. Perhaps we could tear down
>   the singleton instance when the user signs out..We could certainly make this solution work, but the cost is far too great. For one, we’ve lost the simplicity of the dispatch_once solution, a solution which guarantees thread safety and that all code calling [SPThumbnailCache sharedThumbnailCache] only ever gets the same instance. We now need to be extremely careful about the order of code execution for code that utilizes the thumbnail cache.... Since there’s no distinct owner for the singleton instance (i.e. the singleton manages its own lifecycle), it becomes very difficult to ever ‘shut down’ a singleton. **The lesson here is that singletons should be preserved only for state that is global, and not tied to any scope. If state is scoped to any session shorter than “a complete lifecycle of my app,” that state should not be managed by a singleton.A singleton that’s managing user-specific state is a code smell, and you should critically reevaluate the design of your object graph.**"
>
> When the user signs in to a new account, we should be able to
>   construct and interact with a brand new SPThumbnailCache, with no
>   attention paid to the destruction of the old thumbnail cache. The old
>   view controllers and old thumbnail cache should be cleaned up lazily
>   in the background on their own accord, based on the typical rules of
>   object management. In short, we should isolate the state associated
>   with user A from the state associated with user B.

I know one `NSArray` with `PNMessage` objects, that doesn't contain images is not the same and it's easier to handle them, but i'm really confused how should i deal with them.

Originally i would pass the `message` variable inside the `requestFullHistoryForChannel: withCompletionBlock:` to an instance variable called `self.messageGlobal` (that i can use with a singleton in every views) and reset it when the user logs out.

```
//inside the viewWillAppear
[PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel: withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error)

     // self.messageGlobal should be managed by a singleton or appdelegate or use the dependency injection??
     self.messageGlobal = message;

    }];

- (IBAction)logOutButton:(id)sender {

      //disconnect from the PubNub network
      [PubNub unsubscribeFromChannel:currentUserChannel];

      //prepape ivar for the new message history
      [self.messageGlobal removeAllObjects];

      // log out user (i'm using parse.com for managing users) 
      [PFUser logOut] 
}
```

After Stephen's article i feel i'm lost, it would be amazing if somebody could explain the right direction.

My plan is to create a method in the `ViewController1`, that handles the history.

```
-(void)downloadPubNubHistory {

 [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel: withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error)

 // self.messageGlobal should be managed by a singleton or appdelegate or use the dependency injection??
 self.messageGlobal = message;

}];

}
```

In the `AppDelegate` or `ViewController1` i would place an observer to get notified when the current users channel recieved a new message, it's important because i would like the call `downloadPubNubHistory` everytime he or she receives a new message and update the current view with the new content.

```
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:currentUserChannel withBlock:^(PNMessage * msg) { 

  [ViewController1 downloadPubNubHistory]; 

 } }];
```

For example in `ViewController3` i list every message that was sent by **sampleUserB** to the channel of **sampleUserA** (current user), if **sampleUserA's** channel receives a new message from **sampleUserB** on her/his channel i need to reload `downloadPubNubHistory`, and also reload `ViewController3`, because i'm filtering the `self.messageGlobal` in the `ViewController3` to get messages only from `sampleUserB`.

Any opinion and suggestion welcomed, it's possible that i misunderstood the whole concept and i could basically use singleton and reset it everytime when the user log out without any problems, but i would like to utilize the most lightweight reliable solution. If there is any other recommended technique i would love to hear it too.

---

[Original source of the article](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/singletons.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, singleton always was a tool which is served for concrete purpose. I don't see any troubles event with multiuser and their switch based on singleton (you can always reset state of singleton and not try to destroy it).
Because we work a lot with data, we can't afford to initialize some data model all the time when we need to use it, because there will be spend additional time on: allocation & initialization, presetting initial state, maybe loading some data from file system or network. If we will perform all this steps in each view or data object where we would like to manipulate with data - it will kill our app responsiveness and user will have some bad experience.
So, it all depends on how you will code your singleton and how you will use it. If you have multiuser app and some sensitive data should be keep away from another user you can create some User entities and store all required data in it (in your case messages can be passed to it). This entity will be some simple data model or data object and still you will be required to have some class responsible for it. Here you can create some singleton which will be responsible for managing current user and his data (when you specify current user, old one can be deallocated and all data can be pushed into some local storage like CoreData on sqlite).
As I understand, you chat application want to pull out user history after login... You can do it in class which will manage User entity and fetch history as soon as current user will be changed (in you example you call history API each time, when new message arrive to the user - bad idea because history API may be **heavy**). Your PFUser instance can store all required data as for channels on which it should be subscribed or unsubscribed and they can be used during *logOut* process.

Comment: You wrote it's a bad idea to call history API everytime when a new message arrived, but actually i don't really see how can i avoid it. Suppose we have table view where i list every message from userA's channel history. If userA taps a cell (which represent the conversation with userB) a new view will shown with their message history. Until this point everything is clear, after your answer i also totally accept the singleton object, i have no more worries about it. Now i can imagine that solution: userA opens the app, retrieve the history once when the app launched.

Comment: I pass the history array into a new array (singleton object), that will hold the messages. If the client receives a new message i put the new message into the same array where i store the history. Thereafter i have an array that contains every message that userA has/gets on her channel and don't have to call history API always. When she logs out i annihilate somehow the singleton and the app is ready for the new user session. If the user just close the app, but doesn't log out, i just retrieve the history again when it's active again and do the same.

Comment: When the app is in the background i'll use APNS. This way i avoided CoreData and kept everything simple as possible. What do you think, can this concept work in real life?

Comment: My compliance against history usage was because I saw it in your `addMessageReceiveObserver:withBlock:` method usage (basically it mean that history should be pulled every time when user receive new message - this is wrong). You download history when you need it. So if user selected chat with another person, you can try to pull local cache or call history API to get recent N messages. You don't have to annihilate singleton, just clean up user's data in it. As for APNS I'm not sure how exactly you try to use it (your app won't be active when it arrive and there is nothing you can do w/o user).

Comment: Thank you, i think i'm on the right way. But something isn't clear, if i place `addMessageReceiveObserver:` inside the AppDelegate, how can i notify other views from message receive events? NSNotificationCenter is good for this purpose or is there any built-in feature in the PubNub iOS SDK that makes it easier? Or i just add the observer into every view, that i need to reload when a new message arrived, put my reload method inside the block and it'll handle it? `[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:withBlock:^(PNMessage *message){ [tableView reloadData]}];`

Comment: @vv88 Exactly! You can use `PNObservationCenter` not just in AppDelegate, you can use it whether you need to get notifications.