# Retrieve data from NSObject's property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I have class called `GlobalArray` which is an `NSObject`. It has an `NSArray` property called `globalData`.

I'm passing data into `globalData` inside of my `ViewControllerOne.m`, it works perfect, i can print the log in the console. The problem is, that i'm unable to retrieve this data in `ViewControllerTwo.m`.

GlobalArray.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalArray : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *globalData; // why retain?
```

GlobalArray.m

```
#import "GlobalArray.h"

@implementation GlobalArray

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.globalData = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return(self);
}
```

ViewControllerOne.m (GlobalArray.h imported into .h)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:my_channel from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:NO withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {

            GlobalArray *fromHistory = [[GlobalArray alloc] init];
            fromHistory.globalData = message;
            NSLog(@"TEST LOG 1 %@", fromHistory.globalData);

}];
}
```

I try to retrieve it in ViewControllerTwo.m this way: (ViewController.h and GlobalArray.h is imported)

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    GlobalArray *history = [[GlobalArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *sampleArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    sampleArr = history.globalData;
    NSLog(@" TEST LOG2 %@", sampleArr);


}
```

But TEST LOG2 is empty. I think i missed something in the ViewControllerTwo.m, but can't figure it out, for me it seems it's correct.

Comment: Those `GlobalArray` objects are being allocated locally and are not visible outside of those methods.  You want a singleton pattern, however, you need to learn more about variable scope first.

Comment: If you want your `GlobalArray` to be available throughout your app you must turn it into a singleton.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't want a singleton, in my case it wouldn't be a good solution. I just need to access to this array in two other view controllers.

Comment: I stated here why i want to avoid singleton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477242/handling-messages-from-pubnub-history-as-a-global-variable

Comment: You can pass the data from controller 1 to controller 2 by setting a property in the latter. Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: @mxb Yes i'm using storyboard, i can pass data with segues, but the problem is that there is third view controller between `ViewControllerOne` and `ViewControllerTwo`.

Comment: pass the data also to the middle controller, btw for your use case (I'm reading the other post) I think a singleton is the most elegant solution. The article state to avoid abuse singleton, not to avoid them all.

Comment: @mxb My fear is with the singleton is that when userA logs out and userB logs in, maybe the singleton's data won't be changed. These lines make me unbeliever _If state is scoped to any session shorter than “a complete lifecycle of my app,” that state should not be managed by a singleton.A singleton that’s managing user-specific state is a code smell - Stephen Poletto_

Comment: I see. You can create a Session object with the properties required to save your state and bind it somewhere, like in the AppDelegate. In both cases (singleton/appdelegate) you'll have to manage the fact that the user logs in and out. If you decide for the app delegate, it is cumbersome getting the session from [UIApplication sharedApplication] as you need to cast to your specific delegate everytime. Maybe in that case it is better to have a static method. In all the cases you'll have to import the delegate / singleton class.

Comment: @mxb so you say that it's possible with a singleton if i handle user sessions? Where do i need to place the static method? Into my singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to avoid the classic Singleton pattern, you can bind a session object to the app delegate and implement the methods to login / logout:

```
@interface XXXAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

+ (XXXSession *)loginWithUserName:(NSString*)userName password:(NSString*)password;
+ (void)logout;

+ (XXXSession)currentSession;

@end
```

Then you define the data managed in your session:

```
@interface XXXSession : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *globalData;

@end
```

Initialize the session object it in application:didiFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or where it is needed in your application:

```
@implementation XXXAppDelegate {
    XXXSession *_currentSession;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self loginWithUserName: @"Test"];
}

@end
```

In your ViewControllers you can obtain the session as follow:

```
[XXXAppDelegate currentSession].globalData
```

This approach is similar to have a singleton object with the difference that the access to the instance is not offered by the singleton class itself (as stated in the definition of this Design Pattern) but it is implemented in the application delegate.

Comment: I moved login / logout methods in the app delegate as they are more appropriate there instead that in the session object

Answer (score 0):

Of course you'll get empty because you are initializing a separate object of type GlobalArray in your ViewControllerTwo.
This is like you do:

```
Car car1 = [[Car alloc] init];
car1.name = @"BMW";
Car car2 = [[Car alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Car name = %@", car2.name);    <--- this will be empty!
```

You need to keep the GlobalArray variable somewhere to access it later in ViewControllerTwo instead of reinitializing it, or make the GlobalArray class singleton to always return the same instance instead of creating separate instances.

Comment: As an example, where should i store it?

Comment: For example in application delegate, or inside another object accessible globally. This approach is not so good but it's a way to do if you insist not to do singleton.